# ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape When Trying to Offset Bars

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am trying to plot `_lst_one` and `lst_two` on a double bar chart, where the y axis is the score of ACT and SAT (on a scale of 0-1) and the x axis is the scores grouped by 4 values (whether the state required the SAT, ACT, a choice, or had no test requirements).

The shapes of the lists and x_values are correct, I get an error when I try to input `x` to offset the bars.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

labels = ['ACT', 'No Test', 'SAT', 'ACT or SAT']

lst_one = list(states_2018['sat_percent_total'].values)
lst_two =  list(states_2018['act_percent_total'].values)
x_values = list(states_2018['test_required'].values)

x = np.arange(len(labels))  # the label locations
width = .3  # the width of the bars

ax.bar(x - width/2, x_values, lst_one, width, color ='green')
ax.bar(x + width/2, x_values, lst_two, width, color ='blue')
ax.set_xticklabels(labels);
```

Comment: Hey Megan, which line of your code throws the error? Could you edit your question to include the full error traceback?

Comment: `ax.bar` has one superfluous parameter. From the given code and missing data it is hard to guess how the labels correspond to the dataframe. Maybe the intended code would be `x = np.arange(len(x_values ))` and then `ax.bar(x - width/2, lst_one, width, color ='green')` and finally `ax.set_xticklabels(x_values )`?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear the format of your dataframe.  I've synthesized one.

- [bar](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) the **x** and **height** lists need to be same size.  If you source from two columns in data frame this will be the case
- have cut out generating intermediate lists which are not required

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

labels = ['ACT', 'No Test', 'SAT', 'ACT or SAT']

states_2018 = pd.DataFrame({'sat_percent_total':np.random.randint(1,100,10),
                           'act_percent_total':np.random.randint(1,100,10),
                           'test_required':np.random.choice(list("ABCD"), 10)})

width = .3  # the width of the bars

ax.bar(states_2018['test_required'], states_2018['sat_percent_total'], width=width, align="edge", color="green")
ax.bar(states_2018['test_required'], states_2018['act_percent_total'], width=-width, align="edge", color="blue")

ax.set_xticklabels(labels);
```

[image]